Excel Formula: How to filter against an array excluding blank cells?
I have a worksheet tab that contains a table exported from a piece of software used. On another sheet I have a filter function set up to be based on cell input, essentially a quicker way to search specific item numbers than clicking through and typing in the filter menu. Single input worked fine, and I sort of got it working for taking in multiple cells and skipping blank ones but I assume there's got to be a simpler way than what I came up with.
A3:A is essentially just as many order #'s as I want to filter it against, currently only intending on 10 at a time with my current formula (I shortened my example to just 3 entries).
=FILTER('export 2'!A:S,
IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A3)),('export 2'!F:F=A3))+
IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A4)),('export 2'!F:F=A4)+
IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A5)),('export 2'!F:F=A5))))

I cannot include an image because it contains sensitive data, but essentially I'd like to filter against any order # that I put in A2:A*. Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Use MATCH:
=FILTER('export 2'!A:S,ISNUMBER(MATCH('export 2'!F:F,A:A,0)))


That worked perfectly, thank you so much
